# refine the result in full text search

Tags: sql-server-2000

i am using the freetexttable in my search but i am not getting the exact results how can i get the exact results....

Comment: actually i want more results...in my application please tell me how can i refine my result

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are currently doing and what you want it to do to answer that.

Comment: i am making a property search engine in which there is an option of selecting locality in the search... thats why i am using full txt search i want that the results in which required locality is shown but also other related locality also appar in result... but the exact locality should have preference....
thats y i m using freetexttable.

Comment: Can you post the syntax of your query; are you doing your vectors on locality ? Or are you doing it through the thesaurus functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you choose freetexttable over containstable ? Freetexttable ignores ands which means you get more results.

Comment: actually i want more results...in my application please tell me how can i refine my result

Comment: i am making a property search engine in which there is an option of selecting locality in the search... thats why i am using full txt search i want that the results in which required locality is shown but also other related locality also appar in result... but the exact locality should have preference.... thats y i m using freetexttable.